# Lebesgue integral on $[0,1]$ and alternating intervals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am working on the following problem from some old exam:

> For $\ n>0, \ $ a set $\ A_n \subset [0,1] \ $ is defined as $$A_n \ = \
>  \bigcup_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\Bigg[\frac{2k-2}{2^n},\frac{2k-1}{2^n}\Bigg].$$
> Prove that for any Lebesgue integrable function $\ u:[0,1]\to
>  \mathbb{R} \ $ we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{A_n}u(t)\mathrm{d}t \ =
>  \ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}u(t)\mathrm{d}t. \ \ \ \ \ \  (\star)  $$

Thus $\ A_n \ $ is a union of odd intervals from $\ n$-th binary division of $ \ [0,1]. \ $ It is obviously enough to check the thesis for $\ u\ge 0. \ $  In fact,  I believe that I can  check that $ \ (\star) \ $ is correct for simple functions. How to go from there? If $\ u_k \ $ are simple functions monotonically growing up to $\ u, \ $ we have
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \ \lim_{n\to \infty} \ \int_{A_n}u_k \ \mathrm{d}t \ \ = \ \ \lim_{k\to\infty} \ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} u_k \ \mathrm{d}t \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}u \ \ \mathrm{d}t.$$
That would end the proof if we could interchange the limits on the left side. Can we do that? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Just asking: Does it not follow immediately from the dominated convergence theorem ?

Comment: With those two limits on the left side? I don't see how...

Comment: Directly at $(\star)$: Define $u_n = 1_{A_n}\cdot u$, then $\int_0^1 u_n \to \int_{0}^1 u$. Or am I missing something with pointwise convergence?

Comment: But $1_{A_n} \not \to 1$.

Comment: Ohhhh right ${}$

Comment: Maybe check if you can use [Moore-Osgood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Sufficient_condition) (I don't have enough time to do so right now -- and also I would expect there to be a simpler proof but who knows)

Comment: I would expect a simpler proof too...

Comment: Also, it is easy to check this for $L^\infty[0,1]$ functions  and they are dense in $L^1[0,1]$... But I really have to go so I can't try to elaborate on that, sorry